# return undefined error in ajax response while image validation using codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, uploadify

**Below is my code here validation working fine but while no validate at that time else part is working but its return undefined and showing in alert, how remove this undefined**

```
<?php
public function doupload()
{
$upload_config['upload_path'] = './assets/upload/';
$upload_config['allowed_types'] = '*';
$upload_config['max_size'] = '500';
$upload_config['max_width'] = '300';
$upload_config['max_height'] = '300';
$this->upload->initialize($upload_config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('Filedata')) {
$upload_info = array(
'error' => strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors())
);
echo json_encode($upload_info);
}
else {
$upload_info = $this->upload->data();
echo json_encode($upload_info);
}
die;
}
?>  

<script>
'onUploadComplete': function(file, data,response) { 
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.error);   
if(obj.error != '')
{
    $('.msg').show();
}else{
    go_next = true;
    data_arr.push(obj.full_path);       
}
},              
</script>
```

Comment: you have not loaded the upload library  $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);

Comment: @shantanu the library loaded in construct, here I dont use any where

Comment: @MaxBorn undefined what ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam : In ajax response I alert to error whatever return from controller, but while image uploaded error return undefined

Comment: without binding array just add text and test

Comment: @AbdullaNilam - wihout binding array how use CI $this->upload->display_errors()

Comment: i sadi FIRST TEST IT !!!

Comment: @AbdullaNilam - same error showing

Comment: fix it. then you're able pass the arrays. got it

Comment: @AbdullaNilam - Actually in controller else part not find to 'error' so here I pass a blank array but same undefined error showing. EX- if (!$this->upload->do_upload('Filedata')) {
   $upload_info = array(
    'error' => strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors())
   );
   echo json_encode($upload_info);
  }else {
   $upload_info = array('error' => '');
   $upload_info = $this->upload->data();
   echo json_encode($upload_info);
  }